# How to download chrome extension (readable files) from developer dashboard

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have uploaded a chrome extension on webstore but lost the local from my desktop. Is there any way to download the extension back either from webstore or developer dashboard such that I get all my files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just install it and then go to your User Data directory.....
http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory
..then into the directory of the profile you installed it under, then the extensions directory and then the directory with the key of your extension, then the directory with the latest version and youll find all your files.  You can find the key listed on the extension page in chrome in developer mode.  Dont forget to edit the manifest, remove the update url and such.
Or if your on windows (I know it works in XP, never tested vista/7) you can use my convenience tool ExtensionOpener.....
http://forum.valorsolo.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=269&p=1163

Comment: I am using Chrome 17.0 on Windows 7. I am unable to find AppData inside C:/Users/<username>. Also whenever I start Chrome it shows an alert with message "Your profile cannot be used because it is from a newer version of Google Chrome. Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile directory or use a newer version of Chrome".

Comment: I dont have windows 7 or have ever used it, so that doesnt help ;).  But try right clicking on a shortcut to Chrome and pick properties.  There should be an input that says something like target or working directory...basically look for the path to Chrome and copy up to "...\Google\Chrome\" and put that in Explorer, you should hopefully see a User Data directory.  And for your problem with the prefrences.... when you find your User Data directory, go into Default (default Profile) and delete the Preferences file...or try updating your Chrome, shouldnt you be on Dev 19.x.x.x?

Comment: Got it. Actually the folder was hidden, that's why I was unable to find it. I had quite frequent crashes with Chrome dev channel 16.x. Since then I have been using stable version only. Now that you have mentioned it...